# Updating Android UI from custom view

Tags: android, layout-inflater, custom-view

I'm new to Android development, and still having difficulties comprehending how the framework works. I try to write a simple game to get some experience and I'd like to ask for some help with the below.
In my main Activity, I have a few TextViews to show various data from my game, and under those I have a custom View called AnimatedView that has the canvas where I draw my objects for the game itself. Based on the objects on the Canvas, I'd like to update the TextViews to show e.g. number of object, what level the player is at, etc.

The problem is, even though I can get the TextView object with the below code, when I call textView.setText(...), nothing changes on the UI.

The below is a simplified version of my real code, to demonstrate the problem:

***activity_main.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    tools:context="com.danielsh.test.teststuff.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:text="Change this!" />

    <com.danielsh.test.teststuff.AnimatedView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/animView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

***AnimatedView.java***

```
public class AnimatedView extends View {
    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                textView.setText("" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
                textView.invalidate();
            }
        };

        uiHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

I assume that I'm not working with the actual TextView object that's visible on the UI, but not sure what'd be the correct way of doing that.

Any help or pointer to an existing post that deals with the same problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try `textView.invalidate();` after you set Text in it

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi textView.invalidate(); doesn't make a difference for me.

Comment: @tynn handler.postDelayed() is indeed nicer, unfortunately is has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me, what you're trying to do with `AnimatedView`, so I won't be able to give you a real solution on how it would be working correctly, only on what's your issue here. If this is your full implementation, you should maybe try to implement the behavior it in your activity itself.

In your posted `Runnable` you inflate your layout from XML. That means you create new layouts and views and assign these to your local variable. These views are not part of the layout hierarchy displayed in your activity. So when you update the text of the `TextView` you'll never see any changes anywhere.

As a sidenote: Use [`postDelayed(Runnable, long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) instead of creating a new `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks for the more explanation. What you said confirmed my assumption, that I'm not working with the correct View.
So how can I access activity_main.xml's Views from my AnimatedView.java?
Without using inflate (e.g. `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`) `textView` is always null.

Comment: @DanielSH if the `TextView` is not part of the view hierarchy of `AnimatedView`, you shouldn't access it at all. Consider implementing the animation in the scope of your activity.

Comment: Thanks, this is promising. I refactored the code to do the update in `MainActivity.java`, however for some reason the code to update the UI only runs once. 
I've updated my sample, can you see what's wrong with it?

Comment: @DanielSH don't update your question if you change a lot. Just ask a new one for a new problem. There are some issues not related to your original question.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the advice, I'll change this back, and create a new question.